# Add UINavigationBar programmatically with a Done button

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar, modalviewcontroller

So I have a modal view and want to add a UINavigationBar programmatically with a Done button to dismiss this view when the user finishes reading the content.

Any ideas on how to do this and if it's possible purely without using the interface builder?

Answer (score 48):

I am sorry that nobody here actually read your question... here is the code you are looking for:

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
navBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

UINavigationItem *navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];
navItem.title = @"Navigation Bar title here";

UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Left" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(yourMethod:)];
navItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton;

UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Post" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(yourOtherMethod:)];
navItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;

navBar.items = @[ navItem ];

[self.view addSubview:navBar];
```

I hope this helps, good luck :)

Add this code to your viewDidLoad method and everything will construct itself. Mind you, replace the selectors with your own method signatures-

Happy coding

Comment: For iOS 7 set background color with: [navBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]]; and title text color with: [navBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];

Answer (score 7):

It is definitely possible.

Probably the easiest way is to embed the `UIViewController` your are presenting modally into a `UINavigationViewController` and then add the `Done` button, doing something like

```
UIBarButtonItem * doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                            initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone 
                            target:self 
                            action:@selector(dismiss)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
```

and implement a `dismiss` method like follows

```
- (void)dismiss {
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES 
                                   completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you should embed your view controller into a `UINavigationController`. In that way you get the bar "for free". There are several way to do so, but it depends on how your are presenting your modal view.

Answer (score 3):

```
//add done button to navigation bar
UIBarButtonItem *doneBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(userPressedDone)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneBarButtonItem;
```

Then have a method like this somewhere in your view controller

```
-(void)userPressedDone {
    // Action For Done Button Tapped
}
```